# Error JRLoader.loadObject no crea PDF JasperReports 6.0.0

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Hola estoy usando la libreria JasperReport en un proyecto que necesito actualizar, al querer imprimir un documento me sale el siguiente error:

```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:188)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:172)
    at Presentacion.Trip.frmTripRUD.createPDF(frmTripRUD.java:785)
    at Presentacion.Trip.frmTripRUD.btnListaGeneralActionPerformed(frmTripRUD.java:1034)
    at Presentacion.Trip.frmTripRUD.access$3200(frmTripRUD.java:60)
```

Este es el codigo:

```
private void createPDF(Object[][] data) {
    try {
        String path = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
        DataReport newReport = new DataReport(data);
        System.out.println(path + "/src/Reportes/lista-general-clientes.jasper");
        JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(getClass().getResource((path + "/src/Reportes/lista-general-clientes.jasper")));
        System.out.println("paso ");
        JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, null, newReport);
        
        JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(jprint, false);
        view.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        view.setVisible(true);
        
    } catch (JRException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Quizas el problema este en que estoy usando la version 6.0.0 de jasperReports y el codigo lo probe en la 6.17.0 pero, en el proyecto que estoy trabajando necesito usar esas librerias ya que mucho codigo ya esta escrita en esa version y al actualizarla me sale error en otras funcionalidades ya hechas.

la linea 785 que sale en el error es donde declaro la variable report.

De verdad agradeceria la ayuda.

Comment: Si el error esta en la variable ``report`` es posible que sea un error usar ``getClass().getResource("")`` Esto devuelve un recurso que este dentro del mismo paquete o subpaquete al de la clase, usar ``"algunaclase".class.getClassLoader().getResource("");`` para obtener un recurso dentro de cualquier paquete del proyecto por medio del ClassLoader. en mis proyectos ese era siempre el error a la hora de leer imágenes